# Limit of $a_n=f(1)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

[Corrected Question]

We are given that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}=2$$

Prove that the following sequence converges to infinity:

$$a_n=f(1)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=\infty$$

Comment: This doesn't seem like it is possible to solve. For $0 < x \leq 1$ let $f(x)$ be arbitrary. For $x > 1$, let $f(x) = 2x$. Then the first condition is satisfied, but we can arrange the values $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, and hence $a_n$, however we want them. For example, choosing $f(x) = 0$ on $0 < x \leq 1$, we have $a_n \to 0$, but if we choose $f(x) = x$ on $0 < x \leq 1$, the sequence diverges.

Comment: Corrected question. We need to prove that it converges to infinity.

Comment: @NightRa But it doesn't do so necessarily. Reread Michael's comment.

Comment: Corrected question again. The first limit is when x goes to zero.

Comment: @NightRa **Outline:** If you mean $\lim \limits_{x\to \color{red}0}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right)=2$, then $f(x)\overset {x=0}\sim 2x$, therefore $$\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left(a_n\right)=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}(2+1+\dfrac 23+\ldots+\frac 2n)+\text{finite error}=\sum \limits _{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac 2n\right)+\text{finite error}=+\infty$$

Comment: @GitGud thought of that exactly, but didn't figure out why I could use it, but the finite error explains it to me. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @NightRa I like [L.F.](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/56837/l-f)'s [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480624/limit-of-a-n-f1f-left-frac12-rightf-left-frac13-right-f-lef/480643#480643) better. My [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480624/limit-of-a-n-f1f-left-frac12-rightf-left-frac13-right-f-lef/480644#comment1035076_480624) is still there in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $x^{-1}f(x)\to 2 $ as $x\to 0$ then there is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,\;1 \leq nf(\frac{1}{n})$. Hence,

$$n\geq N:\;\;f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\geq \frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow \sum_{k=N}^n f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\geq \sum_{k=N}^n \frac{1}{k}\to \infty$$